# Will iOS backup include a paired Bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: ios, backup, multi-touch

I have an iPad with a broken digitizer. This, of course, renders the iPad useless. Although I would still be able to use it for typing, etc, if only my Bluetooth keyboard was paired to it. But how to achieve that when the touch screen can't recieve input?

So I got an idea.

Can I pair the keyboard with another iOS device, backup that iOS device to my Mac, and then restore that backup to the iPad? Will that include the paired keyboard?

I am (barely) able to unlock the screen of the iPad, so I will be able to sync and restore it from the Mac.

Comment: Why wouldn't you "just try"?

Comment: Well, I actually managed to pair the keyboard using the touch input. But suppose I didn't, maybe I didn't have easy access to another iOS device, and wanted to know if it would work before getting a hold of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth pairing matches two hardware devices, so that pairing records are irrelevant if re-loaded on a different bluetooth adapter (on the new iOS device). Good thinking to get around a hardware repair - if you could somehow turn on assistive touch and try backing that up, you might be able to navigate - but I'm guessing that still needs some amount of digitizer functionality to restore the backup in the first place.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202658

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't expect network settings to be saved and transferred through backup, especially to two different machines, but I could be wrong.